# Placing lists within a figure tag to cite

Tags: html, html-lists, figure

I'm currently creating a portfolio site to send out to potential employers. I want to show them that I am passionate about using clean code that is as semantic as possible. This has lead me to emailing potential employers for advice regarding what's important when doing a portfolio site. After receiving a few replies I realised I needed a coming soon page. This has led me to creating a coming soon page which shows the progress of the portfolio site which in turn shows how I work and how I handle a web project.

As I will be 'citing' all the information I've received I want to add the information in 'list form' but not quite sure how to correctly go about it. I've read an  [article](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/more-thoughts-about-blockquotes-than-are-strictly-required) on the 'alistapart' website recently that suggests I could use blockquotes within a figure tag then add a cite after a `blockquote`.

Just wondering if I could do something like this but with a ul:

```
<figure class="advice">
    <ul>
        <li>Show you are living and breathing web design.</li>
        <li>Portfolios, experience and practical examples of work are critical.</li>
    </ul>
    <figcation>Joe Blogs / <cite>A web agency</cite></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realised I might not have asked the question in the right way but I have decided upon a solution just incase anyone else is wondering.

```
 <figure class="advice">
      <blockquote>
           <ul>
                <li>Show you are living and breathing web design.</li>
                <li>Portfolios, experience and practical examples of work are critical.</li>
           </ul>
      </blockquote>
      <figcation>Joe Blogs / <cite>A web agency</cite></figcaption>
</figure>
```

The reason for this is, for the "cite" to make sense there needs to be "blockquotes". So if the something is cited that is listed then the blockquote must surround the list.

I came to this decision by reading over the alistapart [article](http://alistapart.com/blog/post/more-thoughts-about-blockquotes-than-are-strictly-required) that states this makes sense:

```
 <figure class="quote">
 <blockquote>It is the unofficial force—the Baker Street irregulars.</blockquote>
 <figcaption>Sherlock Holmes, <cite>Sign of Four</cite></figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Therefore it must also make sense if a list element is placed there too.